# What do I call a relational schema without the constraints?

Tags: database-theory

It is common in db theory to define a ‘relation schema’ as consisting of a relation name, the (names of the) attributes, *as well as constraints on the relation*.  A ‘database schema’ is then a set of such relation schemas.

An instance of the database schema consists of a finite set of tuples for each of the relations, which satisfies all of the constraints.

Now what I need is the notion of a relation schema, and sets of such *without* the constraints.  I want to add the constraints separately, and then be able to talk about how some instance of the (constraint-less) schema satisfies the constraints or not.  E.g. define ‘legal instances’ as instances that satisfy the constraints.

Is it defined like that somewhere in the literature?  What are the common names for a db schema *sans* constraints?

Comment: "big mess of rows", "consultant's dream", and "lawsuit factory" come to mind

Comment: @bbaird the context is a theory (!) paper about translating constraints from one formalism to another.  It’s really hard to describe unless you have a name for "instance of this schema except it doesn’t satisfy the constraints"

Comment: How about "*constraintless schema*"? :)

Comment: @bbaird I was going to say "MySQL" but then I remembered that they did add foreign key constraints. :P

Comment: ‘Constraintless schema’ would definitely say what I mean.  «We define a schema to consist of a constraintless schema paired with some constraints» might raise a few eyebrows though.  The mathematician in me leans toward one of ‘pre-schema,’ ‘quasi-schema’ or ‘semi-schema.’  Probably the first to save toner.  But ideally, I’d called it what someone else has called it before me.

Comment: @mabartibin Yea I mean naming things is *hard* but generally picking something that is clearly readable and digestible is a good route to go as long as it's also accurate. A **schema** is just the definition of your database (either *logically* in the context of theory, or *physically* when it exists as an actual database somewhere in practice). There are different *objects* that belong to that **schema** definition, and therefore can be used as adjectives in the English language sense when describing the **schema**. So my vote goes to "*constraintless schema*", just like a Tesla Model 3 is...

Comment: ...an "*engineless vehicle*". (I drive a Tesla, so had to give them a shout-out. :)

Comment: "Schema" (and just about every term) isn't used consistently anyway so just get in the habit of defining a term in context.

Comment: @philipxy, right… we could use “schema” and “constraintful schema”… “constrained schema”… I know:  it’s a *schematic* since it does things where a plain schema doesn’t!

Comment: Re your final question, and apropos of my last comment, probably the most common term for what you are talking about is--and what you are talking about is probably the most common use of this term--"schema". (Here's [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) DB fun--and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029100/3404097).) Just say, let a relation variable name plus a set of attribute names be a X. (Oh--you aren't using "relation" for both a value & a variable are you? Oh dear.)

Comment: We ended up writing «a schema R» for a set of relations and «a schema R with constraints Ω» for the pair of a schema and a set of constraints.  Paper got accepted .